# Git post-receive hook is slow

Tags: git, sh, githooks

I have a post-receive hook that I use to update or dev server. I just set it up. It works, but it is super slow. When I push to the server, it takes about 1 - 2 minutes for the pull to finish, and I don't know why it takes so long. When I do a manual pull, it takes less than 5 seconds.

Why is it taking longer with a hook?

here is the hook's code:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/www
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `cd` changes the directory but the git command is operating on the repository you are pushing to.
This is due to the enviroment Variable `GIT_DIR` which forces Git to use a specified directory.

The variable is set by Git before calling your Hook. Here is a simple Hook that works correctly:

```
#!/bin/sh

export GIT_DIR=/home/www
git pull
```